# MYSQLI::prepare() , error when used placeholder :something

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hi im using mysqli and i saw some examples using placeholder like :something and ?

when i used ? its working, but when i used :something in query like this

> $sql = INSERT INTO food(food_name)
>   VALUES(:food_name)

then error showed up when i called

> $mysqli_object->prepare($sql);

error message sounds like this

> User Error! You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':food_name)' at line

but when i used ? as the placeholder, everything working well, i used PHP 5.3.1 and MySQL 5.1.41

am i missed somewhere, any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqli does not support named placeholders.

[PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) does, using either [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [`execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

(Careful, you can only use a named placeholder once per query.  They aren't too incredibly useful.)