# Calling prepare with mysqli won't fetch data

Tags: php, mysqli, execute, prepare

```
$data = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT amount FROM items WHERE id=:id");
echo 'forward1';
if(!$data->execute(array(':id' => $id)))
    die("error executing".$data->error);
echo '2';
$row = $data->fetch_object();
die('Losing my mind'.$row->amount);
```

This will only echo "forward1", not "error executing..." or "2". It works with *$mysqli->query". If I add quotes '' to :id in the query, it will echo "forward1error executing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you understand the prepared statements syntax and working model.

As in:

```
$data = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT amount FROM items WHERE id=(?)");
            // THIS ^^ actually "prepares" an object to be used in the statement
$data->bind_param("i",$id)
            // ...then you "bind" the parameter for your statement as "i"(nteger)
echo 'forward1';
if(!$data->execute())  // And now you simply run it, with no other args
    die("error executing".$data->error);
echo '2';
$row = $data->fetch_object();
die('Loosing my mind'.$row->amount);
```

I suggest though using something more like

```
$data->execute() or die("error executing".$data->error);
```

The main steps of a prepared statement are:
1. Prepare the query with some placeholder values;
2. "Bind" the required number of values to the query;
3. Execute it!

I fail to see why this is relevant in your case, with such a simple query. I also assume you actually need it for something bigger.
Please let me know if I misunderstood your point or code sample.

Oh, and.. have fun! :-)

Comment: Thank you, everything seems clear after some sleep. Don't know where I got this idea that I could use args in execute, I was so certain about it and its syntax.

Comment: Last couple of days I struggled to get a MySQL query working, and I went to bed after 4-5 wasted hours. I woke up 5 hrs later and solved the problem in ~10 minutes.
It's a common issue, do not worry.
`The Force be with you!`

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your error reporting.

You get a fatal error by accessing the method `execute` on your mysqli::statement after prepare failed. Check if `$data === false` before calling `execute`.

Error message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 1`

See this answer to why this error is triggered: [MYSQLI::prepare() , error when used placeholder :something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256645/mysqliprepare-error-when-used-placeholder-something)

See the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) on how to use mysqli, or use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you, yes I certantly will! $data didn't get false value on the prepare statement as I checked it also. Don't know why. Thanks also for the links!

Comment: Just for the record: I assumed that you are using `mysqli` as your variable is called `$mysqli`. On the other hand your commands suggest that you actually want to use PDO. Named parameters are only available in PDO. Please check if you are using the right extension, as they differ in how to create and execute statements.